# How can I insert repeated NOP statements using Visual C++'s inline assembler?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, inline-assembly, cl

Visual C++, using Microsoft's compiler, allows us to define inline assembly code using:

```
__asm {
    nop
}
```

What I need is a macro that makes possible to multiply such instruction *n* times like:

```
ASM_EMIT_MULT(op, times)
```

for example:

```
ASM_EMIT_MULT(0x90, 160)
```

Is that possible? How could I do this?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyzds0ks.aspx , https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/352sth8z.aspx

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez thank you for links, but these references make not clear how can I solve the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With MASM, this is very simple to do. Part of the installation is a file named `listing.inc` (since everyone gets MASM as part of Visual Studio now, this will be located in your Visual Studio root directory/VC/include). This file defines a series of `npad` macros that take a single `size` argument and expand to an appropriate sequence of non-destructive "padding" opcodes. If you only need one byte of padding, you use the obvious `nop` instruction. But rather than using a long series of `nop`s until you reach the desired length, Intel actually recommends [other non-destructive opcodes of the appropriate length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12564044/366904), as do [other vendors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25545470/long-multi-byte-nops-commonly-understood-macros-or-other-notation?rq=1). These pre-defined `npad` macros free you from having to memorize that table, not to mention making the code much more readable.

Unfortunately, inline assembly is not a full-featured assembler. There are a lot of things missing that you would expect to find in real assemblers like MASM. Macros ([`MACRO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4chx59e.aspx)) and repeats ([`REPEAT`/`REPT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hc8k8wab.aspx)) are among the things that are missing.

However, [`ALIGN` directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwa9fwef.aspx) [*are* available in inline assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1718x77e.aspx). [These will generate the required number of `nop`s or other non-destructive opcodes to enforce alignment of the next instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11277804/366904). Using this is drop-dead simple. Here is a very stupid example, where I've taken working code and peppered it with random `align`s:

```c
unsigned long CountDigits(unsigned long value)
{
   __asm
   {
      mov    edx, DWORD PTR [value]
      bsr    eax, edx
      align  4
      xor    eax, 1073741792
      mov    eax, DWORD PTR [4 * eax + kMaxDigits+132]
      align  16
      cmp    edx, DWORD PTR [4 * eax + kPowers-4]
      sbb    eax, 0
      align  8
   }
}
```

This generates the following output (MSVC's assembly listings use `npad x`, where `x` is the number of bytes, just as you'd write it in MASM):

```c
PUBLIC CountDigits
_TEXT SEGMENT
_value$ = 8
CountDigits PROC
    00000 8b 54 24 04        mov   edx, DWORD PTR _value$[esp-4]
    00004 0f bd c2           bsr   eax, edx
    00007 90                 npad  1       ;// enforcing the "align 4"
    00008 35 e0 ff ff 3f     xor   eax, 1073741792
    0000d 8b 04 85 84 00     
          00 00              mov   eax, DWORD PTR _kMaxDigits[eax*4+132]
    00014 eb 0a 8d a4 24     
          00 00 00 00 8d     
          49 00              npad  12      ;// enforcing the "align 16"
    00020 3b 14 85 fc ff     
          ff ff              cmp   edx, DWORD PTR _kPowers[eax*4-4]
    00027 83 d8 00           sbb   eax, 0
    0002a 8d 9b 00 00 00     
          00                 npad  6       ;// enforcing the "align 8"
    00030 c2 04 00           ret   4
CountDigits ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS
```

---

If you aren't actually wanting to enforce alignment, but just want to insert an arbitrary number of `nop`s (perhaps as filler for later hot-patching?), then you can use C macros to simulate the effect:

```c
#define NOP1   __asm { nop }
#define NOP2   NOP1  NOP1
#define NOP4   NOP2  NOP2
#define NOP8   NOP4  NOP4
#define NOP16  NOP8  NOP8
// ...
#define NOP64  NOP16 NOP16 NOP16 NOP16
// ...etc.
```

And then pepper your code as desired:

```c
unsigned long CountDigits(unsigned long value)
{
   __asm
   {
      mov   edx, DWORD PTR [value]
      bsr   eax, edx
      NOP8
      xor   eax, 1073741792
      mov   eax, DWORD PTR [4 * eax + kMaxDigits+132]
      NOP4
      cmp   edx, DWORD PTR [4 * eax + kPowers-4]
      sbb   eax, 0
   }
}
```

to produce the following output:

```c
PUBLIC CountDigits
_TEXT SEGMENT
_value$ = 8
CountDigits PROC
  00000 8b 54 24 04      mov   edx, DWORD PTR _value$[esp-4]
  00004 0f bd c2         bsr   eax, edx
  00007 90               npad  1     ;// these are, of course, just good old NOPs
  00008 90               npad  1
  00009 90               npad  1
  0000a 90               npad  1
  0000b 90               npad  1
  0000c 90               npad  1
  0000d 90               npad  1
  0000e 90               npad  1
  0000f 35 e0 ff ff 3f   xor   eax, 1073741792
  00014 8b 04 85 84 00
        00 00            mov   eax, DWORD PTR _kMaxDigits[eax*4+132]
  0001b 90               npad  1
  0001c 90               npad  1
  0001d 90               npad  1
  0001e 90               npad  1
  0001f 3b 14 85 fc ff
        ff ff            cmp   edx, DWORD PTR _kPowers[eax*4-4]
  00026 83 d8 00         sbb   eax, 0
  00029 c2 04 00         ret   4
CountDigits ENDP
_TEXT ENDS
```

---

Or, even cooler, we can use a bit of template meta-programming magic to get the same effect in *style*. Just define the following template function and its specialization (important to prevent infinite recursion):

```c
template <size_t N> __forceinline void npad()
{
    npad<N-1>();
    __asm  { nop }
}
template <> __forceinline void npad<0>()  { }
```

And use it like this:

```c
unsigned long CountDigits(unsigned long value)
{
   __asm
   {
      mov   edx, DWORD PTR [value]
      bsr   eax, edx
   }
   npad<8>();
   __asm
   {
      xor   eax, 1073741792
      mov   eax, DWORD PTR [4 * eax + kMaxDigits+132]
   }
   npad<4>();
   __asm
   {
      cmp   edx, DWORD PTR [4 * eax + kPowers-4]
      sbb   eax, 0
   }
}
```

That'll produce the desired output (exactly the same as the one just above) in all optimized builds—whether you optimize for size (`/O1`) or speed (`/O2`)—…but not in debugging builds. If you need it in debug builds, you'll have to resort to the C macros. :-(

Comment: Amazing! C++ template metaprogramming is awesome! It is a really bad thing it does not work for /Od as well :(

Comment: `npad()` is really nice, I wish we could also provide a byte to be inlined with `_emit`, like: `... void npad(BYTE byte) { ...; _asm { _emit byte } }` so we could emit a certain byte N times.

Comment: You should be able to do that, @karliwson. Just pass `byte` as a *template* parameter, rather than a function parameter.

Comment: Amazing!!!! Metaprogramming is the way to go. Sadly it doesn't work for C

Comment: If you're having trouble using the metaprogramming example, you may want to start from here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41102421/visual-c-forceinline-strange-behavior

Comment: Sorry for the earlier pings. The question was migrated back here. Now just have to reopen it lol. If you were somehow involved in its migration back here - Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Base on Cody Gray Answer and code example for metaprogramming using template recursion and inline or forceinline as stated on the code before

```
template <size_t N> __forceinline void npad()
{
    npad<N-1>();
    __asm  { nop }
}
template <> __forceinline void npad<0>()  { }
```

It won't work on visual studio, without setting some options and is not a guarantee it will work

> Although __forceinline is a stronger indication to the compiler than
>   __inline, inlining is still performed at the compiler's discretion, but no heuristics are used to determine the benefits from inlining this function.

You can read more about this here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4714?view=vs-2019

[image]