# Visual C++ __forceinline strange behavior

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inline

I'm trying to force visual c++ compiler to inline a particular function. I know that `inline` or `__forceinline` is just a suggestion. According [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw1hbe6y.aspx), if compiler cannot inline function which is marked using `__forceinline` keyword then it generates warning:

> If the compiler cannot inline a function declared with __forceinline,
>   it generates a level 1 warning.

But I have not got such warning. And when I debug my application I see that there is a `call <inlined function address>` in Disassembly window i.e. my function was not inlined. So how can I check is my function was inlined or not? Does it mean that if no warning was generated then function was inlined and the problem somewhere in other place?

Here is my function:

```
__forceinline SecByteBlock aes_generate_iv(size_t blockSize)
{
    const int seedSize = 32;
    SecByteBlock rngSeed(seedSize);
    OS_GenerateRandomBlock(false, rngSeed, rngSeed.size());

    RandomPool rngp;
    rngp.IncorporateEntropy(rngSeed, rngSeed.size());

    SecByteBlock aesIV(blockSize);
    rngp.GenerateBlock(aesIV, aesIV.size());

    return aesIV;
}
```

Here is circumstances then VC++ cannot inline function (from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw1hbe6y.aspx)):

- The function or its caller is compiled with /Ob0 (the default option for debug builds).
- The function and the caller use different types of exception handling (C++ exception handling in one, structured exception handling in the other).
- The function has a variable argument list.
- The function uses inline assembly, unless compiled with /Og, /Ox, /O1, or /O2.
- The function is recursive and not accompanied by #pragma inline_recursion(on). With the pragma, recursive functions are inlined to a default depth of 16 calls. To reduce the inlining depth, use inline_depth pragma.
- The function is virtual and is called virtually. Direct calls to virtual functions can be inlined.
- The program takes the address of the function and the call is made via the pointer to the function. Direct calls to functions that have had their address taken can be inlined.
- The function is also marked with the naked __declspec modifier.

Comment: May it be the warning is off by default and you haven't enabled it?

Comment: @sharptooth, no, warning Level3 is on, and Treat Warnings As Errors is on. Just checked.

Comment: Some warnings are "off" by default no matter which warning level you have.

Comment: @Bo Persson, I'm compiling with /Ob2 option. Also tried with /Ob1 - same result

Comment: @sharptooth, how can I enable this particular warning?

Comment: pragma warning allows that if you know the warning number. You could also use /Wall but that may cause some thousands, thousands of other warnings being emitted.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 versions of the same warning:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa734011(v=vs.60).aspx

> Compiler Warning (level 1) C4714
> **Visual Studio 6.0**
> 'function' : function marked as __forceinline not inlined

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a98sb923.aspx

> Compiler Warning (level 4) C4714
> **Visual Studio 2015**
> function 'function' marked as __forceinline not inlined

So, to enable the warning, for example, in the Visual Studio 2015 you have to use Level 4 (/W4) instead of Level 3 (/W3) as by default.

Below some advices for how to eliminate such compiler behaviour.
I've resolved these set of cases in the MSVC2015:

1. Recursion calls
2. `SomeType SomeType::operator++(int)`/`SomeType SomeType::operator--(int)`
3. `std::string` returned by value in __forceinline functions

### 1. Recursion calls

```
template <typename T>
__forceinline T int_log2_floor(T v)
{
    ASSERT_GT(v, T(0));

    if (1 >= v) return 0;

    return T((v >= 2 ? int_log2_floor(v / 2) : 0) + 1); // Warning C4714
}
```

One of solution here is just to unroll the recursion:

```
template <typename T>
__forceinline T int_log2_floor(T v)
{
    ASSERT_GT(v, T(0));

    if (1 >= v) return 0;

    T ret = 0;
    T i = v;

    do {
        ++ret;
        i /= 2;
    } while (i >= 2);

    return ret;
}
```

### 2. `SomeType SomeType::operator++(int)`/`SomeType SomeType::operator--(int)`

```
class SomeType
{
    __forceinline SomeType operator++(int) // Warning C4714
    {
        const auto it = *this;
        m_it++;
        return it;
    }

    //...
    iterator m_it
};
```

This one has worked for me:

```
class SomeType;

SomeType operator++(SomeType & r, int);

class SomeType
{
    friend SomeType operator++(SomeType & r, int);

    //...
    iterator m_it
};

__forceinline SomeType operator++(SomeType & r, int)
{
    const auto it = r;
    r.m_it++;
    return it;

    // You still can write here `const auto it = *this; m_it++; return it`,
    // but i hell don't know why this works.
}
```

### 3. `std::string` returned by value in __forceinline functions

This one is really strange, but seems there is some kind of interference between
`__forceinline`-ed functions between `inline`-ed functions because `std::string` basically uses second one - `inline`.

```
template<typename T>
__forceinline std::string int_to_bin(T i, bool first_bit_is_lowest_bit = false) // Warning C4714
{
    std::bitset<sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT> bs(i);
    if (!first_bit_is_lowest_bit) {
        return bs.to_string();
    }

    const std::string bs_str = bs.to_string();
    return std::string(bs_str.rbegin(), bs_str.rend());
}
```

Because the warning has triggered by return-by-value type, the solution here is to return through the parameter instead and inline by `inline`:

```
template<typename T>
__forceinline void int_to_bin_forceinline(std::string & ret, T i, bool first_bit_is_lowest_bit = false)
{
    std::bitset<sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT> bs(i);
    if (!first_bit_is_lowest_bit) {
        ret = bs.to_string();
        return;
    }

    const std::string bs_str = bs.to_string();
    ret = std::string(bs_str.rbegin(), bs_str.rend());
    return;
}

template<typename T>
inline std::string int_to_bin(T i, bool first_bit_is_lowest_bit = false)
{
    std::string res;
    int_to_bin_forceinline(res, i, first_bit_is_lowest_bit);
    return res;
}
```

Needless to say all 3 versions can be workarounded by the `inline` keyword usage instead of the `__forceinline`.